# problem with shared libraries on 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I installed a program, but when I try to start it, it terminates with an error message saying:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I didn't find it in /usr/lib, is there anything equivalent in 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install libmotif4:

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command in a terminal to install `libxm4`

```
sudo apt-get install libxm4
```